# @javax.inject.Singleton not work in tomcat7.0.47

Tags: tomcat, websocket, cdi

Recently, I'm learning about JEE7 websocket api, then I run a demo on newest Tomcat server, but I've found that the annotation `@javax.inject.Singleton` doesn't work, here's the demo code posted in [Jiji_Sasidharan's blog: demo code](http://www.programmingforliving.com/2013/07/jsr356-java-api-websocket-jee7-glassfish.html)

it work's well in glassfish4 server, but if run in Tomcat, `ChatServerEndPoint` instance won't be singleton, but an instance per client(peer), indicates that @Singleton doesn't work at all.

if I want to achieve the same result as it run on glassfish, I have to change the modifier of field : `Set<Session> userSessions` to : `static Set<Session> userSessions`.

in Chapter 6 session 1 of [Tyrus(open source JSR 356) documentation](https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.3/index/lifecycle.html#d0e871)

can anybody explain why, pls help, tks!

Comment: How exactly did you install CDI in Tomcat? Tomcat doesn't ship with CDI out the box and therefore CDI needs to be installed manually in Tomcat. This problem indicates that you simply did it wrong.

Comment: This answer may be helpful then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19003725

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@javax.inject.Singleton` is part of [CDI (Context and Dependency Injection)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/partcdi.htm#GJBNR).

And `javax.websocket` is part of the [JSR-356](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356) effort.

Interestingly, while the spec for `javax.websocket` (section 7.1.1) says that

> Websocket implementations part of the Java EE platform are required
>   to support field, method, and constructor injection using the
>   javax.inject.Inject annotation into all websocket endpoint classes, as
>   well as the use of interceptors for these classes.

The same spec does not mention support for other CDI features, such as `@javax.inject.Singleton`

The spec does however say (see Section 3.1.7) that for singleton Endpoints, you are to use a [`javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html) that overrides the [`.getEndpointInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html#getEndpointInstance%28java.lang.Class%29) and returns the same endpoint instance each time.

All non-tyrus implementations of `javax.websocket` support the spec, as-written. (see Jetty 9.1 and Tomcat)

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that the websocket spec has many gaps when it comes to CDI.  There is no definition of what scopes are active during the invocation of a websocket message.  The scoping rules are the biggest issue, and you will find many incompatibilities along the way.