# Spring + JSF 2.2 + CDI + Tomcat, is it feasible?

Tags: spring, tomcat, jsf-2.2

I really want to use JSF 2.2 but with Spring as I want to use Tomcat as the application server. However based on documentation `@ManagedBean` is deprecated and CDI is the way to go with JSF 2.2+. Thus I was asking if this combination {Spring+CDI for backend and JSF 2.2 frontend} all running on Tomcat will work without glitches?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369356/when-is-it-necessary-or-convenient-to-use-springjsf2-or-ejb3jsf2-or-all-of-the/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995951/trying-to-use-cdi-on-tomcat-results-in-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-targe/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096/what-exactly-is-java-ee/

Comment: @BalusC I know you are a JSF expert and advocate of Java EE but what advice do you have for running full fledged JSF on Tomcat. Also do you advice to use glassfish inn production after Oracle's announcement. Thanks.

Comment: Look for TomEE or JBoss EAP/WildFly. It ships everything out the box you need: JSF, CDI, EJB, JPA and Bean Validation. As you're seemingly already familiar with Tomcat, TomEE would be a logical choice. You can always throw Spring on top of it, for whatever reason you think it'd be more useful. But then there would be no point of using TomEE if you wouldn't be using EJB/CDI/JPA/BV.

Comment: But here my question comes again? Can't I just replace EJB/CDI with Spring's version of CDI since Spring is supposed to support CDI and use JSF as the front-end.