# Java CDI PersistenceContext with Tomcat 8

Tags: cdi, tomcat8

I am using Java CDI with Tomcat 8, with this how to configure database configuration?

Comment: My Beans are configured using steps provided as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995951/how-to-install-and-use-cdi-on-tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 8 is a servlet container and as far as I know, it does not contain any CDI implementation. Are you shipping it with your application?

In order to connect to a relational database, the obvious choice with Java EE is to use JPA, available in [Apache TomEE](http://openejb.apache.org/apache-tomee.html).

Other way is to instantiate Hibernate, myBatis, JOOQ, plain JDBC or anything you would like on your own using CDI producers.

Comment: Thank you @ThePaul. CDI works with base Tomcat 8 with some configuuration. We need to have this dependency  `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.5.Final</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>`