# @Inject properties returns null on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, cdi

I create a class to manage sending emails and i want to inject smtp config via properties file. But i keep got null on my field properties.
This is my code:

```
public class EmailUtils { 
    @Inject
    @PropertiesFromFile("smtp.properties")
    Properties properties;

    public void sendEmail(String destinator, String subject, String body) {
        final String username = properties.getProperty("smtp.email");
        final String password = properties.getProperty("smtp.password");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(properties.getProperty("smtp.from")));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(destinator));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(body);

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
   }
}

public class PropertyReader {

    @Produces
    @PropertiesFromFile
    public Properties provideServerProperties(InjectionPoint ip) {
    //get filename from annotation
    String filename = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(PropertiesFromFile.class).value();
    return readProperties(filename);
}

    private Properties readProperties(String fileInClasspath) {
        InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileInClasspath);

        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(is);
            return properties;
       } catch (IOException e) {
           System.err.println("Could not read properties from file " + fileInClasspath + " in classpath. " + e);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.err.println("Exception catched:"+ e.getMessage());
       } 

       return null;
   }
}

@Qualifier
@Target({METHOD, FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface PropertiesFromFile {
    @Nonbinding
    String value() default "application.properties";
}
```

I tested the code with a simple Main, but it doesn't work. 
I tested it with tomcat and still got NPE on Properties object.
I missed something ?
Please help :)

Comment: Are both of your classes are managed beans ? Injection and producers only work in managed contexts.

Comment: hi Dimpre, should i annotated them ? there were no annotations on the tutorials that i read.

Comment: Tomcat has official distribution with EE technologies, TomEE, few version exists. Very good, and compatible with 'classic' Tomcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please consider doing this Java EE way:

1. If using Tomcat then ensure that you have set it up with a CDI implementation as described in [How to install and use CDI on Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995951/how-to-install-and-use-cdi-on-tomcat) or [Application servers and environments supported by Weld](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/environments.html#d0e4910).
2. Move the JavaMail implementation jars from your application's `WEB-INF/lib` to the Tomcat `lib` directory.
3. Configure your email session in Tomcat by adding the following to it's `config/Context.xml` file:

   ```
   <Context>
       ...
       <Resource name="mail/Session" auth="Container"
         type="javax.mail.Session"
         mail.smtp.host="your mail host here"
         mail.smtp.user="your user name here"
         password="your password"
         mail.from="noreply@yourdomain.com" />
       ...
   </Context>
   ```

   There are other places to put this configuration but this is the simplest to explain here. Refer to the [Tomcat JNDI documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JavaMail_Sessions) for more information.
4. Simplify your code:

   ```
       @Resource(name="mail/Session")
       private Session session;

       public void sendEmail(String destinator, String subject, String body) {
           try {

               Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
               message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                       InternetAddress.parse(destinator));
               message.setSubject(subject);
               message.setText(body);

               Transport.send(message);

               System.out.println("Done");

           } catch (MessagingException e) {
               throw new RuntimeException(e);
           }
       }
   ```

   Your server (Tomcat in this case) looks after configuring the mail session and authentication for you.

A similar mechanism applies to setting up JDBC DataSource objects FWIW.

Comment: Thank you Steve,I use maven3 to manage dependencies, is there another way to solve the issues ?

Comment: At the very least you need to get CDI working in Tomcat. Step 1 gives you pointers for that. Life would be easier for you if you used Tomee, WildFly or Payara servers though.Then you could ignore step 1.

Answer (score 2):

Annotate your `PropertyReader` class with `@Named` and `@ApplicationScoped` to make it known to the CDI Container so it can be managed. Have a blank `beans.xml` in your class path.